# How to get all models/migrations names in laravel and add single new column

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, laravel-migrations, artisan-migrate

I have 88 tables in the database and I need one new column in each the table one single solution is I make a migration and write 88 functions for all tables to add the new column as well as 88 to remove that column.

[image]

Is there any way to get all the table names in 1 variable and then by using `foreach` add a new column by a single piece of code?

1. get all table name in variable
2. by `foreach` loop add new column to that particular variable

```
$allTables=?
foreach($allTables as $singleTable){
    add new column
}
```

But HOW?
I want to add `team_id` in all the tables but I need an optimal solution.

I am using laravel 5.4 version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following.

```
// Get the default database name
$dbName = config('database.connections.' . config('database.default') . '.database');

$tables = DB::select('SHOW TABLES');

foreach($tables as $table)
{
    Schema::table($table->{'Tables_in_' . $dbName}, function($table) {
        // Add the column
        $table->string('some_column');
    });
}
```

To understand what's going on analyze the $tables variable, but should be quite straightforward.

Comment: that's great working great for me thanks for your response love you <3

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this and it's also working, but [your solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45158800/2020834) is better than that, @Artur.

```
class AddTeamIdToNecessaryTables extends Migration
{
    protected $table_names;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->table_names = [
            'accounts', 'suppliers', 'expenses', 'draft_invoices', 'quote_jobs',
            'committed_invoices', 'quotes', 'rate_plans', 'call_categories',
            'prefix_groups', 'draft_items', 'committed_invoice_cdrs', 'committed_items',
            'call_data_records', 'committed_temp_xero_infos', 'did_records',
            'prefixes', 'prefix_cost_prices', 'purchase_items', 'purchase_orders',
            'quote_costs', 'sippy_root_accounts', 'temp_xero_infos', 'sippy_infos', 'committed_jobs'
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        \DB::beginTransaction();
        try {
            foreach ($this->table_names as $table_name) {
                Schema::table($table_name, function (Blueprint $table) {
                    $table->integer('team_id')->unsigned()->nullable()->after('id');
                    $table->foreign('team_id')->references('id')->on('teams');
                });
            }
            \DB::commit();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            \DB::rollback();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        \DB::beginTransaction();
        try {
            foreach ($this->table_names as $table_name){
                Schema::table($table_name, function (Blueprint $table) {
                    $table->dropForeign(['team_id']);
                    $table->dropColumn('team_id');
                });
            }
            \DB::commit();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            \DB::rollback();
        }
    }
}
```